# Django- URL namespace for an app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

This was the root urls.py file for my Django Project:

```
#root urls.py urlpatterns = [...
url(r'^forms/', include(forms_builder.forms.urls)),]
```

I've added a namespace because I want the "forms_builder" URL's to be referenced from another app:

```
#root urls.py urlpatterns = [...
url(r'^forms/', include(forms_builder.forms.urls, namespace='forms_builder')),]

#forms urls.py urlpatterns = [...
url(r"(?P<slug>.*)/$", views.form_detail, name="form_detail"),]
```

But now when I try to access the form_detail page like at for example /forms/my-example I get an error I didn't have before:

> NoReverseMatch at /forms/my-example/ Reverse for 'form_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'my-example'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Edit: I've since given up on this issue, as in the past couple of days I found a way to correctly access this app's urls, without needing to add the 'namespace=...' which was what I was trying to do in this situation. I'm relatively new here, so I don't know if it is appropriate to delete this question or leave it here

Answer (score 0):

[When you add a url namespace the way you use a url in the template is `namespace:name`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

So, in your template you should do `forms_builder:form_detail`.

Comment: I had done so, and that's not the issue. The issue is that now, when I try to open any page, whose URL is from the 'forms_builder' app, I get the error I mentioned. So pretty much, after I assign the app a namespace, it's pages stop working. Remove the namespace, and they work fine. I need the namespace to be able to refer to them from a different app :(